# Create a unique id column by manipulating other columns values

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following two tables `trips` & `segments`:

```sql
CREATE TABLE trips (trip_id INT, session_ids INT[], distance DOUBLE PRECISION);

INSERT INTO trips(trip_id, session_ids, distance) 
VALUES (537165, '{14749,14778}', 1986.56),(542000, '{17577}', 1753.1),
  (545600, '{80652,80782}', 1550),(574674,'{146530}', 2000.3),
  (574679, '{146480}', 1799.1)

CREATE TABLE segments(session_id INT, segment_id INT, length DOUBLE PRECISION);

INSERT INTO segments(session_id, segment_id, length)
VALUES (14749, 1, 89.3),(14749,3,201),(14749,5,500.7),(14778,1,300),
  (14778,2,401),(17577,1,134.9),(17577,3,232.1),(80652,1,102.1),
  (80652,2,300),(80782,1,400),(80782,3,45.89), (146530, 1, 1209.6),
  (146530, 7, 126.7),(146480, 5, 207.4), (146480, 7, 1507.4)
```

From which I am creating a materialized view, joining the two on `session_id`, but creating a new column `id` (manipulating column values in the tables) to uniquely identity each record in the view.

Here are my attempts:

```sql
-- first attempt:
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW example_view 
  AS 
  SELECT t.trip_id * 1000 + s.segment_id AS id
         , s.session_id
         , s.segment_id
         , s.length
         , t.distance
  FROM trips t
  JOIN segments s
  ON s.session_id = ANY(t.session_ids)

-- second attempt
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW example_view2
  AS 
  SELECT t.trip_id * 1000 + s.session_id AS id
         , s.session_id
         , s.segment_id
         , s.length
         , t.distance
  FROM trips t
  JOIN segments s
  ON s.session_id = ANY(t.session_ids)

-- third attempt
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW example_view3
  AS 
  SELECT t.trip_id * 1000 + s.session_id * 100 + s.segment_id AS id
         , s.session_id
         , s.segment_id
         , s.length
         , t.distance
  FROM trips t
  JOIN segments s
  ON s.session_id = ANY(t.session_ids)
```

But in every attempt, I realised there are some rows with duplicate id, like:

```sql
SELECT id FROM example_view
group by id
having count(id) > 1;
```

```
id
545600001
537165001
```

```sql
SELECT id FROM example_view2
group by id
having count(id) > 1;
```

```
id
542017577
545680782
537179749
574825480
545680652
537179778
574820530
```

```sql
SELECT id FROM example_view3
group by id
having count(id) > 1;
```

```
id
589327007
```

How do I create unique `id` column from a combination of those columns in this case?

Here is the [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/kwqW-j47).

Comment: Can you update your post with the expected output and explain the rationale to reach output from your sample input tables in your own words?

Comment: `CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW example_view  AS SELECT t.trip_id :: text || ',' || session_id :: text || ',' || s.segment_id :: text AS id` should provide a unique id column if `trip_id`is the primary key of table `trips`and `(session_id, s.segment_id)`is the primary key of table `segments`

Comment: @Edouard exactly as you said. The columns are the primary key to the table in the order you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the ROW_NUMBER function to get unique IDs as the following:

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW example_view 
  AS 
  SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY s.session_id, s.segment_id) AS id
         , s.session_id
         , s.segment_id
         , s.length
         , t.distance
  FROM trips t
  JOIN segments s
  ON s.session_id = ANY(t.session_ids)
```

[See demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/g6bRspU0)